# Python - create folder using URI path with "file://" scheme

Tags: python

Is there a way to create a folder in Python using a standard URI path, like `file:///C:/work/NewFolder` ?

Comment: use `os.makedir`

Comment: Any issue with `os.makedirs(r'C:/work/NewFolder')`?

Comment: I tried os.makedir, os.makedirs, does NOT work with an URI-like path.